# Mobile Web Application Analytics Tools

Tags: mobile-website, analytics

What are the analytics tools available for a mobile web similar to the "Flurry" which is meant for mobile native applications?

Answer (score 1):

[`Piwik`](http://piwik.org/)

[image: enter image asdasdhere]

Piwik is an open-source Web analytics application developed using PHP and MySQL. It has a "plugins" system that allows for utmost extensibility and customization. Install only the plugins you need or go overboard and install them all – the choice is up to you. The plugins system, as you can imagine, also opens up possibilities for you to create your own custom extensions. This thing’s lightweight – the download’s only 1.9MB.

[`FireStats`](http://firestats.cc/)

[image]

FireStats is a simple and straight-forward Web analytics application written in PHP/MySQL. It supports numerous platforms and set-ups including C# sites, Django sites, Drupal, Joomla!, WordPress, and [several others](http://firestats.cc/wiki/InstallUpgrade). Are you a resourceful developer who needs moar cowbell? FireStats has an [excellent API](http://firestats.cc/wiki/API) that will assist you in creating your own custom apps or publishing platform components (imagine: displaying the top 10 most downloaded files in your WordPress site) based on your FireStats data.

[`Snoop`](http://report.reinvigorate.net/snoop)

[image]

Snoop is a desktop-based application that runs on the Mac OS X and Windows XP/Vista platforms. It sits nicely on your system status bar/system tray, notifying you with audible sounds whenever something happens. Another outstanding Snoop feature is the [Name Tags](http://report.reinvigorate.net/name_tags) option which allows you to "tag" visitors for easier identification. So when Joe over at the accounting department visits your site, you’ll instantly know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most popular is google analytics www.google.com/analytics/

big advantage is that almost all platforms (ao. android, ios, web, ...)  are supported, this makes it easy to compare the performance of all your online properties